# switch theme in javascript

Tags: javascript, themes, uiswitch

I try to switch my themes but ... it's don't work. 
I want a default style ( load when I open the page), and I want to switch with a

I try this but it's don't work :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="script/easyui/themes/dark/easyui.css?v=20130913"/>
```

This is the theme to change and for change :

```
 <script>   var color_mode;
switch (select_box_chosen_color) {
    case "blue":
        color_mode = 'script/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css';
        break;
    case "orange":
        color_mode = 'script/easyui/themes/dark/easyui.css';
        break;
}
var link = $('head').find('link:first');
link.attr('href', color_mode);  </script>
```

And My switch :

```
 <form action="#" action="post">
                        <select name="select_box_chosen_color" id="select_box_chosen_color">
                            <option value="blue">blue</option>
                            <option value="orange">yellow</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit">
                           </form>
```

Comment: So where are you setting `select_box_chosen_color`? :)

Comment: I'm a new in javascript so ... My settings, what do you mean?

Comment: Where in _JavaScript_ do you create the variable `select_box_chosen_color` and assign it a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1: one CSS file

*Assuming you use jQuery*

The only thing you need to do on the `change` event of your `select` is change the css class to the body tag.

```
var theme = $('#select_box_chosen_color');
theme.change(function(){
    $(document.body).prop("class", $(this).find(":selected").val());
}).change(); // optional trigger onload
```

In CSS you use the selected theme as a leading class to start overwriting themes:

```
.myDefault { color: green; }
.blue .myDefault { color: blue; }
```

## Option 2: multiple CSS files

*Assuming you are developing on an `http://` server, NOT on a `file://` system*

If you want to change the file, use an id or data attribute on the `link` tag

**HTML**

```
<link id="themeLink" href="script/easyui/themes/dark/easyui.css?v=20130913" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The options can hold the directory structure.

```
<select id="themeOptions">
    <option value="">default</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

Depending on your directory structure, you should build your url `/` relative from it's directory root and concatenate with the value from the `select` options. Most modern browsers will reload the url, IF it's correctly built, without a problem.

```
var options = $('#themeOptions'),
    dir = 'script/easyui/themes/',
    file = 'easyui.css?v=',
    link = $('#themeLink');

options.change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val(),
        time = new Date().getTime(); // optionally include time to avoid caching

    file = selected.length ? '/' + file : file;
    link.prop('href', dir + selected + file + time);
}).change(); // optional trigger onload
```

I've heard some devices/browsers and or combinations with `iframe` will not reload the style properly. Therefor you should look for a dynamic creation of a `link` tag technique.

Preferably wrap your script functionality inside a DOM ready event.

Comment: Ok, but i don't understand ... I agree, but I do not understand what I have to put javascript code and there is no link to my other sheet syle?

Comment: It's don't work, I don't know why the style is not load

Comment: I've updated my thoughts, hope you understand the principle remains the same.

Comment: Don't work ... When I send my select option ( in a form ) , nothing to do :/